# Flask doubles contents of page when refreshing

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple Flask script which loads a Pandas-file (created in another .py-file) and displays this.
It shows everything, I want... But as soon as I refresh the page,the same content is added!

here is the Flask-thing:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
import Python_script
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    a = Python_script.summary()
    df=pd.DataFrame(a)
    return render_template('simple.html',  tables=[df.to_html(classes='overview')], header='true')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Python_script.summary returns a list

and here's the html-code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

{% for table in tables %}
            
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

what needs to be done so when you refresh, it doesn't add but it simply updates the page?

Many thanks,
Peter

Comment: From the code you provided in your question I can't see why this would happen.  Perhaps the problem exists in your `Python_script.summary()` method.  If you `print(a)` to after that line, does the server console show this 'addition of data' on subsequent requests?

Comment: tried several things,but nothing changes, it keeps on adding ... If I take this ""e=[]
def summaryl():
    a = 2
    e.append(a)
    return e "" as the python script, it keeps on adding. I have no idea what I done wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly from your comment, your `Python_script` looks like:

```
e = []
def summary():
    a = 2
    e.append(a)
    return e
```

If that is the case, then you have a problem. `e` is a global variable, so any time you call summary() method it will add more values to it. The Flask code looks fine. You need to change your logic for `summary` in order not to have data extended.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, if this is the content of `Python_script.py`:

```
e=[]
def summary():
    a = 2
    e.append(a)
    return e
```

Then you add a debug line to the Flask route:

```
import Python_script
@app.route("/")
def home():
     a = Python_script.summary()
     print(Python_script.e)

     # ...
```

You will see that `Python_script.e` is a global variable and `2` is appended to that list on subsequent requests.

A quick fix may be to make `a` global within the Flask app, by moving the line which assigns it.

```
import Python_script
a = Python_script.summary()

@app.route("/")
def home():
     print(Python_script.e)

     # ...
```

Now subsequent requests do not append `2` to the list.  By doing this `a` is assigned *when the server process starts*, rather than *when the request is handled*, because that line was moved out of the Flask route, and to the global level.

If you're trying to implement a way to maintain this list in real-time, then global variables are not the way to go, this is the job of another storage backend.